# JSF, CRUD, Hibernate create new user with combo box

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, primefaces, crud

I have a problem with my app CRUD with jsf/primeFaces & hibernate.

when I want add a new Directer and choose the user exist on combo box, the new directer create but with a new user. So I don't want my method create to add a new user but I want it to choose one from combo box

this a picture of my app when I choose a user from combo box
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=93505615082015160710.jpg

and this is the new user create 
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=15849215082015160818.jpg

and this my method create

```
@Override
public boolean create(Directeur directeur) {
    boolean flag;
    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.save(directeur.getCompte());
        session.save(directeur);
        tx.commit();
        flag = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        flag = false;
        tx.rollback();
    }
    return flag;
}
```

so plz help me and thanks in advance :)

Comment: You got that user's ID ? and Does Directeur mapped to class on your code or just Directeur is a User

Comment: If you want just to update and that `directeur ` object contains an ID then use `session.update(directeur)` instead of `session.save(directeur)`

Comment: Why do you have two calls to `save()`?

Comment: Tiny : I did 2 save coz I got error : Unsaved transient entity, Dependent entities, Non-nullable association(s)

Comment: @karimmohsen I want create a new directeur and give him a user exist

Comment: @RagnarLodbrok you got that user's ID ?

Comment: @karimmohsen what? I didn't understand your question :p